# simple html dom get 2 tags for one foreach

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How to call 2 tags for one foreach with simple html dom?

```
<?php
require_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$str='<img src="./1.jpg" /><span>image1</span><img src="./2.jpg" /><span>image2</span>';//still have more 'img' and 'span'
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find('img') as $content){
    echo $content.'<br />';
    //echo <span> inner html
}
?>
```

I want to get the result like:

```
<img src="./1.jpg" />
image1

<img src="./2.jpg" />
image2
```

one `img` and behind `span` for one unit. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this.

```
$img = $html->find("img");
$span = $html->find("span");

for($i=0;$i<count($img);$i++) {
  echo $img[$i] . "<br />" . $span[$i]; 
}
```